# Battery authenticity, reliability, health and Windows 10 battery health report

Tags: battery-life

I recently purchased a "refurb" laptop/tablet.  I was particularly concerned about the condition of the battery as the tablet is 2014 vintage.   When asked as to the condition of the battery, the seller said "Will be working as new".

The laptop arrived dead, and required to be powered for a fair while (not sure exactly how long, maybe 15 minutes) before it would even start.  This is particularly worrying to me, as I understand Lithium Polymer batteries need to be stored partially full or they take a significant life hit.

On startup I went into the BIOS that reported the battery health as **excellent**  however when I asked Windows for a battery report it stated that the Design capacity was 33,951 mWh however the full charge capacity was 26,640mWh (and it did not show a cycle count).  FWIW the battery reports as being manufactured as Samsung SDI, with a serial number of 548, and type LiP.

1. The Name is reflected in the health report as "Dell VJF0X449", however nothing comes up for a Google search of that.  This number does not match the DP/N number 0VJF0X on the back of the battery nor does it appear to be a valid service tag.  **Does this imply anything about the battery being a fake**?
2. I always understood that a battery that charges to 80% of the original capacity was due for replacement.  By my calculations this battery is down to 78.5% - however the laptop is reporting the health as *excellent*.  **What does this mean in terms of remaining battery life?**    Relatedly, **does this contradict the claim of a battery that the battery will be working as new?**

Comment: VJFOX appeara to be an alternate code for the battery - nit sure where the 449 comes in